# Kernel of a ring homomorphism is prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$\varphi: A\to B$ be a ring homomorphism.

We see that $\ker(\varphi)=\varphi^{-1}(0)$ and we know that if $(0)$ is prime ideal (equivalently $B$ is an integral domain) then $\ker(\varphi)$ is also prime ideal.

I am searching for the reverse direction. Can we say $\ker(\varphi)$ is prime then $B$ is an integral domain? I feel some contradiction, yet could not find.

Is reverse direction is correct, or can you give me a hint about it.

How can we weaken the conditions without imposing surjectivity and injectivity that double direction is satisfied with additional conditions.

Comment: If $\phi$ is not surjective you cannot say anything about $B$.

Comment: Note that "$(0)$ is a prime ideal" is only equivalent to "$B$ is an integral domain" if you are working with commutative rings with unity. $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the condition that the ideal $(0)$ is a prime ideal (if $A$ and $B$ are ideals such that $AB\subseteq (0)$, then either $A\subseteq (0)$ or $B\subseteq (0)$), but is not an integral domain. If you are assuming commutativity, you should say so explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\varphi\colon R\to S$ is a surjective homomorphism of commutative (unital) rings and $I=\ker \varphi$ is a prime ideal, then by the isomorphism theorem, $S\cong R/I$, and the latter is clearly a domain (this is easy to check directly).

If $\varphi\colon R\to S$ is not surjective, this is not necessarily true. For example, if $R$ is any domain, then $R[x]/(x^2)$ clearly isn't a domain, but the kernel of the natural embedding $R\to R[x]/(x^2)$ is $(0)$, which is a prime ideal (since $R$ is a domain).

Answer (score 5):

I assume every ring considered is commutative
If the kernel is a PRIME IDEAL
we can only say that the image of $\varphi$ is an integral domain. This image is a subring of $B$. But a subring being an integral domain says nothing about the whole ring: it can very well ave zero divisors.

We can take the polynomial ring with real coefficients, and then quotient it be an ideal generated by any degree 3 polynomial(they always have one real root). This quotient ring $B$, is not an integral domain, and the set of real numbers will be a subring ( actually a field.)

Now define $\varphi: \mathbf{R}\to B$ sending  every real number  to itself. The kernel now is (0) a prime ideal, but $B$ is not an integral domain.

Comment: "If the kernel is an integral domain" should be "If the kernel is a prime ideal". And, this assumes commutativity, which is not stated.

Comment: Thanks, Arturo Magidin. Edited my post now.